Majorization equivalence
If $ x\in\mathbb{R}^n $, we note $x_{[1]}\geq\cdots\geq x_{[m]}$ the permutation that arranges $x$ in a nonincreasing order. For vectors $ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n $, we note $ x \prec y $ if $\sum_{i=1}^k x_{[i]} \leq \sum_{i=1}^k y_{[i]},  k = 1, \ldots, n-1$
with equality when $ k = n$.
Let $q$ be a number between $0$ and $1$. Suppose I have a vector $ p\in\mathbb{R}^n $ such that $p_i\geq0$ for all $i$, $S:=\sum_{i=1}^np_i\leq1$, and $1-S\geq\frac{1-q}{n}$. Is true that $p_{[1]}\geq q$ if and only if $(q,\frac{S-q}{n-1},\cdots,\frac{S-q}{n-1})\prec p$?

A simple counterexample reads as follows:
Consider $n=2$, $q=\frac18$, $p=(\frac14,\frac14)$.
First let us check that all the assumptions are satisfied.

$q\in(0,1)$ $\checkmark$
$p_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ $\checkmark$
$S:=\sum_i p_i=\frac12\leq 1$ $\checkmark$
$1-S=\frac12\geq\frac 7{16}=\frac{1-\frac18}2=\frac{1-q}n$ $\checkmark$
$p_{[1]}=\frac14\geq\frac18=q$ $\checkmark$

However, the vector $v:=(q,\frac{S-q}{n-1})=(\frac18,\frac{\frac12-\frac18}{2-1})=(\frac18,\frac38)$ is not majorized by $p$ because
$$
v_{[1]}=\frac38>\frac14=p_{[1]}\,.
$$

As now I'm working on the proof, I found I need to add a hypotheses, I'll modify the question soon.

@randomexchanger I adjusted my counterexample to match your new setting. For your information: making substantial changes to your original question is considered bad etiquette; in the future please ask a separate question in such a situation.
